# Simple Big Theta, $\Theta$, notation definition

Tags: asymptotics

Could it be said that:

$f(x) = \Theta (g(x))$ if, for some large $x$, the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ differ only by a constant scale factor, i.e. either $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{C}$ or $f(x) = Cg(x)$, where $C = const$.

?

Could you help me define/explain it the simplest possible way?

Comment: No. Please check the definition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations

Comment: @Did yes, f(x) is bounded above and below by the same function g(x), i.e. g(x) is both smaller and larger, this what confuses me.

Comment: No, this is (not what your question says and) not what the definition says (either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can not say that,

( consider an example that in a program code their are 1000 lines of code and by a true condition check 600 lines can be skipped than the minimum lines executed will be 400 and maximum line executed will be 1000. )

$f(x) = \Theta (g(x))$ this only gives you the idea that,
$$
c_1g(n)\le f(n)\le c_2g(n)
$$
this means for any value of n the minimum possibility is $c_1g(n)$ and maximum possibility is $c_2g(n)$. Consider an example where you have given   $f(x) = \Theta (n)$ and you found that 
$$
10n\le f(n)\le 10000n
$$
then this means for any value of n the maximum possibility is $10000n$ it can not be equal to $1000000n^2$ for any n.

By assuming $f(n)=Cg(n)$ you are saying that it is fixed for all $n$ which is not the case. You can not find **a single constant** which **satisfy** the minimum and maximum possibility for complexity.